# Update table query from another table postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 update table queries in posgresql that returns successful but the updated table is empty when I checked
Query 1

```
UPDATE tt
SET Name=subquery.Name1,
    id=subquery.id1
FROM (SELECT id1,Name1
      FROM  tt1) AS subquery
WHERE tt.id=subquery.id1;
select * from tt;
```

Query 2

```
with t as (
    select t0.id as rowid, t1.Name1 as calculatedvalue
    from tt t0 
    join tt1 t1 on t0.id = t1.id1 
)
update tt
set Name = t.calculatedvalue
from t
where id = t.rowid;
select * from tt;
```

Comment: If the table is empty after the update, it was empty before the update already.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I updated table tt and executed the queries again but tt did not update